# Python decrypting bytes and keeping them in a list as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code, where user has to enter a string. Then, I encrypt this input using the cryptography module and save it in a text file along with a \n so that every new input is on a new line. after that, whenever user types "view", I want to decrypt all of the previous inputs and store them in a list as strings. So far I have only done the first part of encrypting and storing, but cant manage to write a code for the second part.
This is what I have:

```
elif menuchoice == "crypt":
    os.system('cls')
    while True:
        chooseyourscore = input("          >>> ")
        if chooseyourscore == "view":
            # all of the encrypted data gets decrypted and stored in a list individually here.
        else:
            encryption = open("crypted.txt", "ab")
            encryption.write(crypter.encrypt(chooseyourscore.encode()))
            encryption.close()
            newline = open("crypted.txt", "a")
            newline.write('\n')
            newline.close()
            continue
```

Comment: This won't work if the encrypted data contains a newline.

Comment: how else do you think I can store the encrypted data, so that i can tell them apart?

Comment: There are a number of ways, but the simplest which would allow you to keep your current design almost unchanged is to base64-encode the encrypted data and then write it out. There is a `base64` python module that makes it easy. The base64 output is guaranteed not to contain newlines.

Comment: yes, but how do i distinguish where first decrypted data ends and where the second one starts? user has to enter multiple inputs and i need to store all of them in a text file, so how do i tell them apart afterwards if i am not allowed to use \n?

Comment: If you base64 encode the ciphertext then you can use newlines to separate the individual ciphertexts.